# Definite integral as limit of sum $\int_{a}^{b}\sin(x)dx$

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals, summation, trigonometric-integrals

I learn calculus and get stuck. I need help

We have $\int_{a}^{b}\sin(x)dx$, need to calculate using integral sums, so we split $[a,b]$ into $n$ equal parts: $dx \to h=\frac{b-a}{n}$. So

$$\sigma_{n} =\sum_{i=1}^{n}h\times \sin(a+i\cdot h)$$
Multiply both side to $2\sin(\frac h2)$ and use formula $\cos(\beta)-\cos(\alpha)=2\cdot \sin(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})\cdot \sin(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2})$ where $\alpha=a+(i+\frac{1}{2})\cdot h$ ,$\beta=a+(i-\frac{1}{2})\cdot h$

We will get this: $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sin(a+i\cdot h)=\frac{1}{2\cdot \sin(\frac{h}{2})} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n}2\sin(a+i\cdot h)\cdot \sin(\frac{h}{2})=\frac{1}{2\cdot \sin(\frac{h}{2})} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n}[\cos(a+(i-\frac{1}{2})\cdot h)-\cos(a+(i+\frac{1}{2})\cdot h)]$$

and then the book says that it (the sum $1$ to $n$) is equal to $$\frac{\cos(a+\frac{1}{2}h)-\cos(a+(n+\frac{1}{2})h)}{2\sin(\frac{h}{2})} $$
and I can't understand this.

Attaching Image for the Same
[image]

Comment: The sum  here is telescopic sum. (It is of the type $\sum (a_i-a_{i+1})$.

Comment: and what $a_{i}$ and  $a_{i+1}$ are in this example? and what i is?

Comment: $a_i=\cos (a+(i-\frac 1 2) h)$

Comment: thank you very much <3 .. I will think about it

Answer (score 1):

Use the sum of finite geometric series and $e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t:$
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(a+kh)= \Im \sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{i(a+kn)}=\Im e^{ia} \sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{ihk}= \Im e^{i(a+h)}\frac{e^{inh}-1}{e^{ih}-1}.$$
$$\implies S=\Im e^{i(a+h)} e^{inh/2} \frac{\sin(nh/2)}{\sin (h/2)}=\frac{\sin (a+h+nh/2) \sin(nh/2)}{\sin (h/2)}.$$